# How to hide values of certain form fields to the end user before submitting it (from the source?)

Tags: php, html, forms, security, hidden-field

I'm using the creditsystem.com/ws API.

In order to send requests to creditsystem on my page, I have to specify the account username and password in my form (this is an account received from creditsystem).

Obviously, I can't show those values to the end user. The fields will be hidden, but the user could browse the code and see the username/password of the creditsystem account.

How to do this securely?

One idea I had was to call a secure page via ajax (and sending a token), which will then call another ajax and return the response from the creditsystem. But I'm not sure whether this would work and whether this would be a correct approach.

Comment: I can't find the creditsystem.com API. Is that an arbitrary name?

Comment: If you are meant to send the user to their site with sensitive data you have to prefill: run away! That company can't be worth your time. However, it sounds so strange to me I would rather think (and hope) that you have misunderstood the documentation a little.... Usualy would be for _you_ to do a request to the system, which give you some reply (tokens, urls, whatever) you can then use to send the user to his proper goal.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific: this is the site we're using: https://www.creditsystem.com/ws . Also, the two fields that are needed in the form are the ones for the login.

Comment: @Wrikken I'm not sure what you mean. That company (which I mentioned in my previous comment) requires an account name and password received from THEM in order to be able to perform certain user credibility checks. It's a system that checks certain people - e.g. my form input is someones Full name, SSN, Address (+ accout name and passwd I have at their site), etc. and as a response we get the specified user's Employment history, etc. On our site, we perform the check before a payment process.

Comment: You're assuming that the users' browser is going to contact this remote service, log in, send data, etc. You're not. At least you shouldn't be. Any contact you have with the remote service is going to be done on the server. In PHP. Hopefully using some form of encryption. Then the browser never has any of this information and the user can view the source HTML to their hearts' content as it will not contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to collect the form data inputted by the user, then using *curl* you could send a POST request to the website, in which you include your username, password and the other data provided by the user. In this way the call to the API is done server-side and not client-side, avoiding any problem concerning your username/password visibility.

You can find a lot of examples on the web: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+curl+post.